# Laravel: showing 2 or 3 random details on show page

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm making the show page and displaying the detail using foreach. However, sometimes it shows 2 or 3 random detail as well. I thought it was because I'm using 'foreach.' so is there another way to send data without using 'foreach?'

**Route**

```
Route::get('/users/{user_id}', [UserController::class, 'show'])
    ->name('user.show');
```

**Controller**

```
public function show(User $user_id)
{
    $user = User::find($user_id);
    $books = Book::all();
    
    return view('front.user.show', [
        'user' => $user
    ],
        [
            'books' => $books
        ]);
}

public function show(User $user_id)
{
    $user = User::find($user_id);
    $books = Book::all();
    
    return view('front.user.show', [
        'user' => $user
    ],
        [
            'books' => $books
        ]);
}
```

**Blade**

```
@section('list')
    <h2 class="user">Users</h2>
    @foreach($user as $user)
        @if(empty($user->num_books))
            <p>no author</p>
        @else
            <p class="user_item">{{$user->Book->name}}</p>
            <p class="user_item">belongs to :{{ $user->Company->company_name}}</p>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    <span class="">
      <form method="post" action="{{ route('user.destroy', ['user_id'=>$user->id]) }}">
        @csrf
          @method('DELETE')
        <button type="submit" class="btn" onClick="return confirm('are you sure？');">
            Delete
        </button>
      </form>
    </span>
@endsection
```

Comment: why are you finding user when the user is already type hinted? I mean  ``show (User $user_id)`` and  ``$user = User::find($user_id);`` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, ``@foreach($user as $user)`` using the same variable name for iterating data from and to assign !!!

Comment: mmm, even tho i tried, it also an error....

Answer (score -1):

i hope this work

$books = Book::with(['user'])->get();